Request for more information on closed question

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: Strange Solarflare (SFN8522?????)issue
I do not understand how this is marked as a question about a host or server I am asking about how to identify hardware from its PCI Device ID / Subsystem when its not listed in a pci data base. This is a question that related to general process of diagnosis of network hardware.
Can you help me to understand how asking about a layer 1 network question is not allowed to be asked. Thus seems like the very core of what a network engineering stack exchange was built for.

As explained in the comment, [su] is the place to ask the question.

"Thus seems like the very core of what a network engineering stack exchange was built for." No, that is not network engineering. That is an endpoint problem. The network is what is between the endpoints. There are many SE sites to deal with endpoint problems.

Please see the help center for topics you can ask about here. Hosts and their hardware are not among them.
